# Passport js - Should I return the users encrypted password or token?

Tags: javascript, angular, passport.js, mean-stack, passport-local

This is a pretty open question but I just can't get a straight answer no matter where I look. The question is in the title but...

Should I return the user's encrypted password or token on user login

**Extra Info**

I'm running a MEAN stack application with Angular5. I'm using sessions for the user and storing it in MongoDB. So from what I understand, the session cookie is what used to authenticate the user for extended sessions and not the password (I haven't gotten to Facebook or Twitter strategies but from what I understand the cookie verifies the user instead of the token that Facebook/Twitter gives me correct?).

I do want to pass user data to my Angular application and store in the browser local storage for quick, non-server-side verification that the user is logged in. This is only for aesthetic reasons such as displaying username and profile picture. Restricted POSTs and GETs still require server-side verification using a passport. So my question is since the session is saved in the cookie, is there any reason to send the password or token to the user/browser? Even though the password is encrypted (using bcrypt), it still seems like an unnecessary security hole to send it at all. Is there a reason that I might encounter in the future where I would want the password stored in the browser?

Comment: Rather than sending the password/token, you could store the user information in the cookie as well, so that the information is valid for as long as the session or cookie is valid. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yess, that does. How would you do that though? Also is that safe?

Comment: Depends on how sensitive the information is. If you want to prevent any user information stored on the client, you could send the user information in the response when you validate the session. 

This post covers a similar topic: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36318/store-username-in-cookie-for-a-web-site

Comment: The information I want to store is not at all sensitive. It seems the article is saying that the information (such as a password) is as safe as the users computer and that I would be exposed only as much as the user has permission (which would be very limited for almost all users). My question is, if I didn't use their password in the session would what would be the effects? Is there any reason I should? Is there any advantage to storing it in the session or with the user?

Comment: It isn't advisable to store the password in the session, the whole point of the `session cookie` is to prevent unnecessary storage of passwords to auth user during for the session duration.

Comment: Ok cool, thats what I wanted to know. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is no, you do not and SHOULD NOT pass the sensitive data back to the front end.

What I normally do is when I return a "User" object back as a response to the front end, I run it through a helper function that filters out sensitive data such as the encrypted password and the salt, etc...

Comment: Or maybe just dont use `*` in your querys ;p

Comment: agreed, but sometimes you might need the sensitive data for some actions on the server side